# What does intercept actually mean in a simple linear model?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-model

Given y = a + b*x, does "a" represent simply an intercept or mean y?

For y = a + b*ln(x), is there a need to interpret the intercept "a?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a model like
$$
E[y] = a + b*x
$$
$a$ represents the mean value of $y$ for all observations where $x = 0$. Whether or not this is meaningful will depend on whether $x=0$ is meaningful in your situation.

Similarly, in
$$
E[y] = a + b*ln(x)
$$
$a$ represents the mean value of $y$ for all observations where $ln(x)=0$, i.e. $x=1$. Again, if this is a valid situation, then you can usefully interpret $a$.

Comment: Nice answer. A small caveat is that the interpretation hinges on the units of $x$. If $x$ is first transformed by subtracting its mean (and maybe dividing by it standard deviation), then $a$ can be interpreted as the expected $y$ for someone who has the average $x$. Often that is more meaningful/interesting. Obviously, you can't do that and use the natural log as well. If you have a regression with no $x$, then you can interpret $a$ as the arithmetic average of $y$.